# XLS file is opened but not displaying the right data

Tags: javascript, html, macos, xlsx, xls

I am generating an xls file using a template. The file is exported and could be open with LibreOffice or Open Office, yet when trying opening it with Numbers on mac i get [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxD9J.png) . This is the template I am using to generate the file. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
TEMPLATE_XLS = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">' +
            '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8"/>' +
            '<head><!--[if gte mso 9]>' +
            '<xml>' +
            '<x:ExcelWorkbook>' +
            '<x:ExcelWorksheets>' +
            '<x:ExcelWorksheet>' +
            '<x:Name>{title}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions>' +
            '</x:ExcelWorksheet>' +
            '</x:ExcelWorksheets>' +
            '</x:ExcelWorkbook></xml>' +
            '<![endif]--></head>' +
            '<body>{table}</body></html>';
```

Comment: I am not sure that this question is somehow related to programming

Comment: thought maybe it's related to the template  am using

Comment: You have to provide template and your `javascript` code, without that nobody could help you

Comment: I already put the template I am using and the result I am getting

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually caused because I was trying to open an html file with a false extension(xls). I needed to use sheetjs library for the exportation with xlsx extension.